# Inspection of K66 ROM with IAR EWARM

Tags: debugging, embedded, iar, kinetis, ewarm

I am currently using IAR EWARM 9.10 to develop an application for Kinetis K66. I am in the process of debugging a hard fault and I noticed that when I inspected certain locations - using EWARM's memory view - in the K66 Flash, the contents were reported as double dashes ('--'). How should I be interpreting this?

Example attached...[image]

Comment: What does the data sheet say? Is it possible that there is no memory? Or does the GUI interpret unprogrammed cells (all ones: 0xFF) in this way? What does its manual say? Is there an option that you could change?

Comment: Usually means non-mapped or reserved memory.

Answer (score 3):

The dashes (`-`) in the Memory visualization window means *unmapped memory*.

In a Kinetis device where the installed Flash memory ends at `0x000FFFFF`, the "Memory 1" window shows up like this on the end of the region:
[image: IAR EW ARM Memory Window]

For the Kinetis devices, the flash memory available for the user's code is discontiguous and within `0x0000_0000~0x0000_03FF | 0x0000_0410~END_OF_FLASH`.

This is due a "flash configuration" region (`0x0000_0400~0x0000_040F`) reserved for the `FlashConfig` section.

For a similar device, using IAR EWARM 9.30:
[image: seems right]